# Insert JSON array to postgres using psycopg2.extras.execute_values

Tags: json, postgresql, psycopg2

I would like to insert `JSON` arrays into postgres using `psycopg2.extras.execute_values`, but I get

`psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'dict'`.

Using `json.dumps()` on `JSON` columns works, but it doesn't for `JSON` array columns, when I do it, I get

`DETAIL:   "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.`

Unfortunately I need to use `psycopg2` module to accomplish this (it's doable in pandas easily).

Full code:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df.to_numpy()]
cols = ','.join(list(df.columns))
query = "INSERT INTO %s(%s) VALUES %%s" % ('mytable', cols)


with self.db.connect() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as db_cursor:
        execute_values(db_cursor, query, tuples)
```

Comment: Looks like a type mismatch.  Your column is some kind of SQL array type, not JSON.

Comment: @jjanes the column is a JSON array, `JSON[]`.

Comment: 1) Don't use `JSON[]` that is Postgres array of JSON types e.g.: `select array['[1,2,3]'::json, '[4,5,6]'::json]; {"[1,2,3]","[4,5,6]"} pg_typeof  json[]`. That will cause you no end of headaches. What you want to use is proper `json(b)` e.g. `select '[1,2,3]'::json; [1,2,3]`. 2) DO NOT do `... VALUES %%s" % ('mytable', cols)` use proper [Parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), that will also save you headaches especially those coming from SQL injection. 3)

Comment: 1) The `json` example should have been: `select '[[1,2,3], [3,4,5]]'::json; [[1,2,3], [3,4,5]]` to match the  `JSON[]` example. 2) You get `...can't adapt type 'dict'` because `psycopg2` is expecting a `list` for a Postgres array type. See [Type adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types).